# How I can to reduce 9V battery to 7.4V - it is for R/C model

Tags: voltage, batteries

What size of resistor I can use to reduce the 9V rechargeable battery to 7.4V output for R/C model please?
I would like to use rechargeable 9V batteries instead of 7.4V as it´s handy to go a grab one normal (non-rechargeable) 9V battery from shop near by when my own batteries goes flat out.
Most likely it will be wired resistor used between 9V battery adapter and input to the small motherboard on the R/C helicopter.

Comment: Forget it, I just found that common 9V batteries does have much smaller mA than Li-On battery packs...

Comment: why closed? (and especially as "too localized"?) User has a legit question. The "R/C helicopter" information may be extraneous, but otherwise I don't see anything wrong here.

Comment: If it's actually a helicopter, there may be several amps of current draw which is more than a lot of regulators can handle.  And keep in mind that small helis can be *interesting* to fly with things hanging from them - though it is true that before lithium batteries, people did sometimes fly electric helis on power tethers, so it can be done.  Also remember that motor heating can be an issue in flight duration in addition to battery life (though not carrying the battery mass would lessen the workload).  If lithium polymer, 7.4V is the "drained" voltage with 8.4v the freshly charged one.

Answer (score 6):

You can't do it with just a resistor, as voltage drop is related to current, and current is related to speed.

What you want is an adjustable, or 7.4v fixed "low dropout" voltage regulator.